# Duplicate Layers in eCognition

Tags: classification, multi-band, ecognition, image-segmentation

I am attempting to use eCognition Developer to segment and classify 5-band UAS imagery. When I go to create a new project in eCog and input my imagery (individually selecting the five .tif files), it is creating duplicate layers. I should only have 5 layers in my project, but it is returning 11 layers. Red, Green, Blue, NIR, and Red Edge layers are all duplicated, and an extra (undefined) band is input with them.

Below is a screenshot of my Image Object Information screen (after a segmentation run) so you can see what layers I am referring to. I have my layers named according to what they represent, and the duplicates are just "Layer 1,2,etc."

[image: duplicate layers] [image]

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening, so I only have my 5 layers of interest within my project?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from 'Image Aliases' under 'Process'?

Comment: Edited with Image Alias window screenshot

Comment: Did you 1) create a new project, and 2) edit the layer names in the create project GUI? When I use this approach, I do not have duplicate layers.

Comment: Yes, I used the project GUI.

Comment: @hugonbg, the files are opening normally as .tif, so I'm not sure why they are duplicating in eCog

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem, try opening the files from another folder and see if they are opened normally. 
Sometimes for some reason it opens the .tif and the .recommand (virtual Raster) together, even if you have not selected the two. OVR is created when you open a Raster in ecognition.